# How to send pause and continue signals from child process to parent?

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I have an application where the child needs to suspend and continue the parent process at times. But when I send the `SIGSTOP` signal from child to parent, it not only suspends the parent, it suspends the child process too, which I was expecting to send `SIGCONT` signal from to revive the parent.  Is there any way to achieve this functionality. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far ? So that we can help.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. It seems like you're sending the signal to the process group that include the parent *and* the child. Perhaps you need to create a new process group for the child?

Comment: Independent from your actual problem: Requiring the child to stop the parent using `SIGSTOP` might to be a wrong design. Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interprocess Communication fork() - Timing wait() and/or sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053799/interprocess-communication-fork-timing-wait-and-or-sleep)